# Is there any tool to check the format of .mht file?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, format, mhtml

I have a nearly 20M .mht file which is generated by TestComplete during automation testing. The file generated in batch mode cannot be opened by IE. The   node seems to be correct, but just no content shown on the page. However, if I generate a the .mht file from TestComplete in GUI, I can open it in IE then.

As IE doesn't tell me any more details when nothing is shown, I am trying to find some toolkit which can help me to identify the problem in the .mht file.

(I tried to compare 2 .mht files line by line, but nothing special.)

PS:
I tried to open the broken 2 files with Firefox UnMHT add-on, and view the source code with Firebug:

The good one get the main  parsed correctly:

```
<div src="unmht:///file.5/D:/workspace/test_result.mht/root.xml" id="logroot" style="width: 1430px; height: 472px;">
```

The bad one doesn't have it parsed correctly:

```
<div src="http://localhost/root.xml" id="logroot"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried opening it with some other browser; e.g. one that has a working code inspector and gives meaningful error messages? See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.mht

Comment: Could you please post here the script code that exports the log from TestComplete? Also, please clarify which version of TestComplete you have.